# Getting results from two different tables using a join

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have the following tables:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| t_classroom                               |
+-------------------------------------------+
| PK | id                                   |
|    | admin_user_id                        |
|    | name                                 |
|    | students                             |
+-------------------------------------------+

+-------------------------------------------+
| t_shared                                  |
+-------------------------------------------+
|    | admin_user_id                        |
|    | classroom_id                         |
|    | expiry                               |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

I want to write a query that will pull all classrooms that an `admin_user_id` has access to. In essence, I want a union of classroom rows when I search by `admin_user_id` in the `t_classroom` table as well as classroom rows when I search by `admin_user_id` in the `t_shared` table. I made the following attempt:

```
  SELECT
    id,
    admin_user_id,
    name,
    students
  FROM
    t_classroom
  WHERE
    admin_user_id = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    c.id,
    c.admin_user_id,
    c.name,
    students
  FROM
    t_classroom c
    INNER JOIN t_shared s 
    ON c.id = s.classroom_id
  WHERE
    admin_user_id = 1
```

Does the above look correct? Is there anything more efficient/cleaner?

Comment: would you please provide some sample data and result??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how much data you have you could probably get away with just using an `IN` clause to look at the other table.

```
  SELECT
    c.id,
    c.admin_user_id,
    c.name,
    c.students
  FROM
    t_classroom c
  WHERE
     c.admin_user_id = 1 
  OR c.id IN ( select s.classroom_id from t_shared s where s.admin_user_id = 1 )
```

Your union wont work because you're left-joining to the `t_shared` table and checking only the classroom admin user.

If you join the shared room you would also end up with duplicates and would need to distinct the result too.

**Edit:**

Because of the large number of rows it might be better to use an exists check on the 2nd table.

```
  SELECT
    c.id,
    c.admin_user_id,
    c.name,
    c.students
  FROM
    t_classroom c
  WHERE
     c.admin_user_id = 1 
  OR EXISTS ( select 1 from t_shared s where s.classroom_id = c.id AND s.admin_user_id = 1 )
```

Comment: Just to give an indication of size, both tables would be in the 100s of millions of rows each

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is fundamentally fine, the only two problems I can detect when eyeballing your query are:

- You need to write `s.admin_user_id` instead of `admin_user_id` in the last line to avoid an error message, because there is a column of that name in both tables. Best practice is to *always* qualify column names with the table names.
- You might want to use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` if you want to avoid a duplicate result row in the case that both tables have `admin_user_id = 1` for the same classroom.